# How to integrate XRAY with karate framework

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, karate, jira-xray

Currently i am doing a POC on integrating karate with XRAY?
how exactly to integrate Xray with Karate Framework

Comment: do you only want to have visibility of the results in Xray? Where do you want to manage the Gherkin specification?